# Unable To Access Webpage Within Same Network

Tags: php, iis, networking, xampp, port80

I recently created a simple php site.

On my pc which is hosting the webpage, can be accessed through browser by
http://localhost/dataentry/

So, I then transferred to another new hosting pc. I was trying to start the apache server unfortunately it fails and I reconfigured to another port which is 9090 then it is working again. Therefore, in order to access the webpage from the localhost. I have to type the following address which is http://localhost:9090/dataentry/ instead.

Then, i use another pc to access the site within the same network. Details are as following:

- **PC A - Host the server (IP:10.83.1.18)**
- **PC B - PC that would like to    access the site (IP:10.83.1.17)**

Unfortunately, I got the following error at **PC B** which is shown below.

[image]

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

When was finding for solution previously, I came across a method to check for the used port which is shown here. However, as I'm at a bank environment, I'm not sure if it is safe for me to terminate following listed services there. That was why I try to change the port number instead which lead to above issue.

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Before I attempt to change the http://localhost/dataentry to http://localhost:9090/dataentry , I came across this similar error that I googled which has a template or layout like this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried via the actual IP? (`http://10.83.1.18:9090/dataentry/`)

Comment: Hi, yes. I tried with PC B via the browser. Neither http://localhost:9090/dataentry/ nor http://10.83.1.18:9090/dataentry/ work unfortunately

Comment: Can you ping it successfully?

Comment: Yup. First thing, I did was to ping and it is successful

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to access the site locally, but not from the network, and you're certain the URL is correct, then the most likely culprit is the Windows Firewall. To validate this, try accessing the site again after turning off the firewall on the server, or if check if the remote port is responding by using telnet. Ex:

```
> telnet 10.83.1.18 9090
```

If the port is blocked by the FW, telnet connection would be refused.

---

If you've confirmed that the firewall is not blocking the connection, then your next bet is to check the permissions for the account used for Anonymous User access. In your case, this seems to be the built-in IUSR account (if this is IIS7 per your comment below). Linked TechNet article explains how to [Configure the Anonymous Authentication Identity in IIS7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966(v=ws.10).aspx).

One important extra is to remember that since you're using PHP, the related binaries should also be accessible to the IUSR account with Read/Write/List permissions. If the PHP code is attempting to write something on the server based on user interaction (e.g. file uploads, config file changes, etc.), then IUSR should also have Write permission to the specific destination folder.

Comment: Hi, yes the telnet is successful. My firewall by default has been turned off. So, I try to turn on the firewall and adding a new rule that allow connection from port 9090. However, it is still the same problem.

Comment: In that case, check if the security settings on the site allow the _anonymous IIS user_ Read & Execute access to the web folder. The name of this account differs by both O/S and IIS versions, but a quick search would help you find out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By the way, I'm kinda new to the IIS things that you were talking about earlier. But then, I tried to google and found a link which is https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ded7af2-fcb7-4ed2-b007-e19f971f6e13.mspx?mfr=true . I'm wondering if this is a correct link for me as a guidance to configure the security settings?

Comment: Well, I wish could test them immediately from the guide provided unfortunately I have limited access to the affected PC and therefore I have no choice except to study and understand the things first. Before I could hands on the affected PC later on

Comment: The link in your comment is for IIS6. You probably have a later version running on that server. Same concept, but different implementation, so it would help to know which version is running.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, the IIS for that affected PC is IIS 7